# How to get first element of tuples and values of nested dictionary within list

Tags: python, list

How do I select first element of a tuple and values of nested dictionary that's inside a list?

```
organization = [('research', {'size': 0, 'values': [], 'start': 0}), ('marketing', {'size': 2, 'values': [{'user': {'name': 'anna', 'id': 10, 'displayName': 'Anna'}, 'category': 'Secretary'}, {'user': {'name': 'bob', 'id': 11, 'displayName': 'Bobby'}, 'category': 'Manager'}], 'start': 0}), ('sales', {'size': 1, 'values': [{'user': {'name': 'claire', 'id': 13, 'displayName': 'Clarissa Claire'}, 'category': 'Secretary'}], 'start': 0})]

department = [[x['user']['name'], x['category']] for nest_list in organization for x in nest_list["values"]]
print(department)
```

Expected:

```
department = [[marketing, anna, Secretary], [marketing, bob, manager], [sales, claire, Secretary]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this part:

```
for nest_list in organization for x in nest_list["values"]
```

`nest_list` is a tuple (all the tuples in `organization`), and you want `x` to go through all the objects in the `values` list which is the second member of each tuple, but you jump right to `values`. So the end there should be `nest_list[1]["values"]`-- you need to get into the second tuple element BEFORE going into `values`.
Then in your list defintion you'll also need to include `nest_list[0]` as the first element of each element list so that you can have the department as you want. The `department =`  line would thus look like this:

```
department = [[nest_list[0], x['user']['name'], x['category']] for nest_list in organization for x in nest_list[1]["values"]]
```

Comment: Yup it worked. But I'll try to re-write it not using list comprehensions. I think it's easier to understand with regular nested for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
# Define your list
organization = [('research', {'size': 0, 'values': [], 'start': 0}), ('marketing', {'size': 2, 'values': [{'user': {'name': 'anna', 'id': 10, 'displayName': 'Anna'}, 'category': 'Secretary'}, {'user': {'name': 'bob', 'id': 11, 'displayName': 'Bobby'}, 'category': 'Manager'}], 'start': 0}), ('sales', {'size': 1, 'values': [{'user': {'name': 'claire', 'id': 13, 'displayName': 'Clarissa Claire'}, 'category': 'Secretary'}], 'start': 0})]

# Create empty lists to be used by the loop
employee = []
employee_list = []

# Loop through each department
for counter in range(0,len(organization)):
    # Check if there are any entries by looking at the size key
    if organization[counter][1]['size'] > 0:
        # loop through each user
        for user in range(0,len(organization[counter][1]['values'])):
            # for each user, pull out the Name and Category, and add it to the employee list
            employee = [organization[counter][0],organization[counter][1]['values'][user]['user']['name'],organization[counter][1]['values'][user]['category']]
            # Add each employee as a nested list in the Employee list
            employee_list.append(employee)

print(employee_list)
```

There may be some refinements that could be made here but this is what I was able to cobble together.

Edit: After I said this I was able to refine it a bit:

```
# Define your list
organization = [('research', {'size': 0, 'values': [], 'start': 0}), ('marketing', {'size': 2, 'values': [{'user': {'name': 'anna', 'id': 10, 'displayName': 'Anna'}, 'category': 'Secretary'}, {'user': {'name': 'bob', 'id': 11, 'displayName': 'Bobby'}, 'category': 'Manager'}], 'start': 0}), ('sales', {'size': 1, 'values': [{'user': {'name': 'claire', 'id': 13, 'displayName': 'Clarissa Claire'}, 'category': 'Secretary'}], 'start': 0})]

# Create empty lists to be used by the loop
employee = []
employee_list = []

# Loop through each department
for counter in range(0,len(organization)):
    # Loop through each user based on the size key
    for user in range(0,organization[counter][1]['size']):
        # for each user, pull out the Name and Category, and add it to the employee list
        employee = [organization[counter][0],organization[counter][1]['values'][user]['user']['name'],organization[counter][1]['values'][user]['category']]
        # Add each employee as a nested list in the Employee list
        employee_list.append(employee)

print(employee_list)
```